# Get User Properties on NewForm.aspx in Add-In

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I'm trying to get user properties on newform but i get this error :

> JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'PeopleManager' of undefined or null reference

This is the Schema.XML of my list :

```
<Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" JSLink="~site/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js|~site/Scripts/sputility.js|~site/Scripts/GetRemainingDays.js"/>
```

And here is my code to run GetRemainingDays.js :

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(initializePage, "sp.js");
alert("test");

function initializePage() {
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("jquery");
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserProperties,    'SP.UserProfiles.js');

    //getUserProperties();
});
}

function getUserProperties() {

//var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = clientContext.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Settings");
var listItem = list.getItemById(1);


clientContext.load(listItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    if (listItem.get_item('ManagerSource') == 'O365 Active Directory') {
        alert(listItem.get_item('ManagerSource'));
        getO365Properties();
    }
    else
        if (listItem.get_item('ManagerSource') == 'Managers List') {
            alert(listItem.get_item('ManagerSource'));
            getManagerListProperties();
        }

}, function (sender, args) {
    console.log(args.get_message());
});
 }


function getO365Properties() {
var userProfileProperties;

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

var currentUser = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();

clientContext.load(currentUser);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    var loginName = currentUser.get_loginName();

    var profilePropertyNames = ["InitialLeaveDays", "LeaveDays"];
    var userProfilePropertiesForUser =
        new SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser(
            clientContext,
            loginName,
            profilePropertyNames);

    userProfileProperties =    peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertiesFor(userProfilePropertiesForUser);

    clientContext.load(userProfilePropertiesForUser);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        //console.log("initial leave days :" + userProfileProperties[0]);
        //console.log("leave days :" + userProfileProperties[1]);
        //alert("Initial Leave Days: " + userProfileProperties[0]);
        //alert("Remaining Leave Days: " + userProfileProperties[1]);
        var initialLeaveDays = userProfileProperties[0];
        var remainingLeaveDays = userProfileProperties[1];
        document.getElementById("label_leaveDays").innerHTML = "Your   remaining leave days are: " + remainingLeaveDays;
    }, function (sender, args) {
        console.log(args.get_message());
    });

}, function (sender, args) {
    console.log(args.get_message());
});
}
```

Error happens on line     var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

in getO365Properties function.

Any ideas how to correctly include SP.UserProfiles.js?

Answer (score 1):

After some trying, I found that this works whereas `SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(...)` does not.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('userprofile', 'SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager', getUserProperties);
```